# Login with Facebook through Instagram oAuth

Tags: ios, facebook, instagram, instagram-api

Heyo,
I'm receiving reports from our users that they are unable to Connect their Instagram account within our iOS Application. This issue started to arise about 4 months ago (give or take).

I was able to implement the basic oAuth 2.0 back and forth hand shake using the Instagram Developer API. **All works fine when a user enters their Instagram credentials** (and has been working for the last 3 years (see screenshot)), but we noticed when Facebook introduced the "*Continue with Facebook*" option (we didn't add that) on their oAuth landing page, it ceases to function correctly. As a matter of fact, it just breaks, and is not allowed.

So my question is either 1 of 2:

1) How can we simply remove the Facebook option (perhaps there's a hidden option we don't know about)?

OR

2) How might we make it work so that in the 5% use-case that when a user decides to "*Continue with Facebook*", it would properly connect their Instagram account.

---

As a side question; What does *Continue with Facebook* even mean when we're asking the user to connect their instagram account? We are not interested in their FB account (or any of that info). We are solely requesting their Instagram timeline, username, and follower count.

[image: In App Instagram oAuth]

Comment: Did you find any solution? @user3242466

Comment: I posted a more detailed question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74918616/facebook-login-through-instagram-error-validating-verification-code , any thoughts are appreciated